# How do I make my bubble sort algorithm go through all entries in my array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I have an array which stores highscores to a quiz. I have a for loop that should get the bubble sort to go through all entries, however it doesn't function as intended and seems to

All the scores before the sort appear like this:

`[(3, ), (0, ), (1, ), (0, ), (3, ), (0, ), (0, ), (3, ), (69, )]`

And after the sort is 'completed', they appear as:

`[(3, ), (1, ), (0, ), (3, ), (0, ), (0, ), (3, ), (0, ), (69, )]`

As you can see, they appear to have sorted to an extent but it doesn't fully loop back to the start and resort until they are fully in ascending to descending order.

The code for this is:

```
        swapScores = True
        while swapScores == True and lengthHighscore >= 0:
            swapScores = False
            for counter in range(i, lengthHighscore - 2):
                if leaderboardScores[i] < leaderboardScores[i + 1]:
                    tempScore = leaderboardScores[i]
                    leaderboardScores[i] = leaderboardScores[i + 1]
                    leaderboardScores[i + 1] = tempScore
                lengthHighscore = lengthHighscore - 1
                i = i + 1
                swapScores = True
```

Any help at all would be great, thank you!! My code probably isn't as efficient as I would like but I'm really going for functionality over efficiency at this point haha :)

Comment: Why are they in arrays like `(1, _)`. I don't understand why they aren't just [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Why do you want to use bubble sort when there is a native `sort` that will certainly  outperform your code?

Comment: And can I also OT just ask why do bubble sort which is inefficient over the builtin sorting alternatives? I understand if it’s a purely educational purpose but just checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your implementation of bubble sort:

- `i` is not reset to 0 in the iteration of the outer loop, which means that the second time the `range` of the inner loop is evaluated, it is an empty range. In fact, that range should always start with 0.
- That range should go up to, and including `lengthHighscore - 2`, so the range should be `range(lengthHighscore - 1)` instead of `lengthHighscore - 2`.
- `lengthHighscore` should not be reduced in the inner loop, as that will make the outer loop exit after the inner loop finishes. It should be reduced in the *outer* loop.

The following are not breaking the algorithm, but still deserve to be corrected:

- `swapScores = True` should happen in the `if` block, otherwise it does not really help to short cut the algorithm.
- `counter` and `i` will be equal if you fix the above errors, so then you could just use `i` and drop `counter`
- Python has a nice syntax to swap values without using an explicit temporary variable
- The outer loop can also be implemented with a `range` so that you don't have to explicitly decrease `lengthHighscore`. An `if not swapScores` can then be used to break out of that loop as a short cut.

Corrected code:

```
for last in range(len(leaderboardScores) - 1, 0, -1):
    swapScores = False
    for i in range(last):
        if leaderboardScores[i] < leaderboardScores[i + 1]:
            leaderboardScores[i], leaderboardScores[i + 1] = leaderboardScores[i + 1], leaderboardScores[i]
            swapScores = True
    if not swapScores:
        break
```

This will sort the scores in descending order. If you need the order to be ascending, then change the `if` condition to use `>` instead of `<`.

Obviously, there is no need to implement your own sorting algorithm, as Python has a `sort` method and a `sorted` function. These will do the job faster than any custom implementation using Python code.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily sort your list of tuples using `sorted`.

```py
leaderboardScores = [(3, ), (0, ), (1, ), (0, ), (3, ), (0, ), (0, ), (3, ), (69, )]

# sort ascending
sorted_asc_leaderboardScores = sorted(leaderboardScores, key = lambda score: score[0])

# sort descending
sorted_desc_leaderboardScores = sorted(leaderboardScores, key = lambda score: score[0], reverse=True)
```